# why the hex address is 14 character?

Tags: c++, variables, hex

in the hex address like: 0x7fffd7c24334 why number of digits is 14? is it 14 character for every hex address? I try it for some variable like double and int but it was just 14 character. is it obey some rules? thanks for all answers.

Comment: e.g. the hex notation for address 0 is 0x0. Which you could also write as e.g. 0x000000000000 if you want.  What are you actually asking for ?

Comment: It is certainly compiler, processor, and operating system specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

12 hex digits (with leading 0x) mean 48 bits. That is 256 TB of virtual address space. Read wiki on AMD64 (I assume that you are on it, right?) architecture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Comment: could you give me more information about 12 characters? what is the range of this hex numbers?

Comment: 12 hex digits == 48 bits => the limit the CPU can handle concerning ram address size, follow the link provided in by the answer to details